I don't understand why this solution used Bayes Theorem instead of the regular formula for conditional probability.
When I view the solution to this problem, I understand the calculations but I don't understand why those calculations were done.
Below is the question that I'm reading

A theme park conducts a study of families that visit the park during a year. The fraction of such families of size m is $\frac{8-m}{28}$ , $m = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7$


For a family of size m that visits the park, the number of members of the family that ride the roller coaster follows a discrete uniform distribution on the set $\text{{1, … , m}}$.
Calculate the probability that a family visiting the park has exactly six members, given that exactly five members of the family ride the roller coaster.

I recognized the two distributions

X = the size of the family visiting the park and is distributed according to $\frac{8-m}{28}$
Y = the number of family members that ride the roller coaster and this is a uniform discrete distribution with the pdf $P(Y=m) = \frac{1}{m}$

I recognize that I need to find $P(X=6| Y= 5)$.
How do I recognize that this should be solved using Bayes Theorem

$ P(X=6| Y= 5) = \frac{P(Y=5|X=6)P(X=6)}{P(X=x)}$

Instead of just using the conditional probability formula?

$P(X=6| Y= 5) = \frac{[P(X=6)  \text{ & } P(Y=5)]}{P(Y=5)}$


I haven't check if the proofs you give are correct, but any prover can use anything in his or her proofs if he or she wants. Moreover, nobody can "recognize that something should be proved using" something else. You and the prover got different ideas. So what?

@Plop This is a sample question from the Probability exam for the Society of Actuaries. They have a list of past questions with solutions.

Do you know $P(Y=5),?$ If so feel free to use that formula but I believe we don't know $P(Y=5),.$ Edit: at this point I notice that your second bullet point is wrong. That $P(Y=m)$ should be $P(Y=k|X=m)=1/m$ for each $k=1,...,m,.$

@KurtG. Why would this be a discrete uniform distribution P(Y=y) = 1/m? Since there are only 7 groups, the probability of P(Y=5) = 1/7. Edit: I just saw your edit. I think that is the part that I didn't realize when I first read the question.

In plain English $P(Y=k|X=m)=1/m$ days that for a family of size $m$ the probability that $k$ members ride the rollercoaster is $1/m,.$ That is another way of phrasing that paragraph you quoted from the given task.

What do you mean by $P(X=6)  \text{ & } P(Y=5)$? Is "&" some operation you perform on two numbers, or are you trying to express the probability that $X=6$ and $Y=5$? Also, check the denominator in the "Bayes Theorem" formula.

The two formulas are the same thing, because for two events $A$ and $B$ with positive probability, $$\Pr[B \mid A]\Pr[A] = \Pr[A \cap B] = \Pr[A \mid B]\Pr[B].$$
That said, the definition of $Y$ needs refinement, because it is only when $Y$ is conditioned on the event $X = m$ that it is uniformly distributed on $\{1, \ldots, m\}$. As such, you would write
$$Y \mid X = m \sim \operatorname{DiscreteUniform}(1,m),$$
and
$$\Pr[Y = y \mid X = m] = \frac{1}{m}, \quad y \in \{1, \ldots, m\}.$$
To understand why it is incorrect to write
$$\Pr[Y = y] = \frac{1}{m}, \quad y \in \{1, \ldots, m\},$$
it suffices to observe that $$\Pr[Y = 7] = \frac{8-7}{28} \cdot \frac{1}{7} = \frac{1}{196} \ne \frac{1}{7},$$
because in order for all $7$ family members to ride, you have to have a family with $7$ members to begin with, which occurs with probability $1/28$; then, given such a family, there is a $1/7$ chance that all $7$ ride.  Whereas, $\Pr[Y = 1]$ would intuitively be much larger, since all families have at least $1$ member.  Indeed, we know $\Pr[Y = 1] > \frac{8-1}{28} = \frac{1}{4}$, because we know $1/4$ of all families comprise a single member, and in such a case, that single member must be the sole rider.  So $\Pr[Y = 1] > \Pr[Y = 7]$ and the unconditional probability distribution of $Y$ cannot be uniform.
With this in mind, we can see how the calculation should proceed:  we are asked for $\Pr[X = 6 \mid Y = 5]$, and the natural thing to do is to leverage what we already know about the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$.  This is what immediately suggests Bayes' theorem, since we can easily calculate $\Pr[Y = 5 \mid X = 6]$ from the fact that $Y \mid X = m$ is discrete uniform.
The only remaining subtlety of the calculation is to determine $\Pr[Y = 5]$, the unconditional probability that exactly $5$ family members ride.  For this, we require a family size of at least $5$; i.e., $X \ge 5$ or equivalently, $X \in \{5, 6, 7\}$.  Then we would write
$$\Pr[Y = 5 \mid X = 5] = \frac{1}{5}, \quad \Pr[Y = 5 \mid X = 6] = \frac{1}{6}, \quad \Pr[Y = 5 \mid X = 7] = \frac{1}{7}.$$  Combine this with the probabilities of selecting a family of the respective sizes, we have
$$\Pr[Y = 5] = \sum_{m=5}^7 \Pr[Y = 5 \mid X = m]\Pr[X = m],$$
which is the application of the law of total probability.


How do I recognize that this should be solved using Bayes Theorem ... instead of just using the conditional probability formula?

You chose by which ever numerator is easier to find.
$$\mathsf P(A\mid B) = \dfrac{\mathsf P(B\mid A)\,\mathsf P(A)}{\mathsf P(B)}=\dfrac{\mathsf P(B\cap A)}{\mathsf P(B)}$$
